# Amplifier for sensor signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I'm working on a project that utilizes a sensor that requires no power supply of its own but
produces current upon reacting to the active material, the produced current requires amplification to make it readable using external data collection equipment (basically the Arduino).

Now according to the [datasheet](https://www.dart-sensors.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/16mm_breath_alcohol_sensor_product_datasheet.pdf), the specifications of the amplifier are described as below:
Feed output into an I/V amp. A good quality low noise op-amp is needed, and a dual supply (+ and -) is essential

I tried searching for amplifiers with these specifications but I don't seem to understand what's going on. Most of these amps are converting from 5 V to 24 V for example, and that won't work on Arduino, right? and what does I/V mean?

How am I supposed to choose the right amp with only this given info? The datasheet didn't mention any other info.

Comment: The datasheet contains an example circuit that does I/V conversion and even that does not use a dual supply but a single supply. What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Feed output into an I/V amp. A good quality low noise op-amp is needed, and a dual supply (+ and -) is essential.

An I/V amp is a current to voltage amplifier, or transconductance amplifier, or virtual ground amplifier (all three mean the same thing). The sensor presumably has a current output, that's most useful when fed into a short circuit.

The comment about dual supply implies that the sensor output both sources and sinks current.

This is the simplest possible circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe2Glp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The resistor defines the transconductance of the amplifier. In this case 10 kΩ means that an input current of 1 uA would generate an output voltage of 10 mV. You pick the resistor value according to the gain you want between your sensor and your ADC.

This amplifier would require a dual supply to source and sink current about ground at the input. Its output would also swing above and below ground, which is inconvenient for an Arduino.

You say the sensor requires no power supply. That implies it can be referenced to a mid-rail voltage instead of ground. That means you could replace the circuit with a mid-rail referenced amplifier, fed with a single 5 V along with your Arduino, like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD8Xul.png)</sup>

The amplifier and Arduino share the same 5 V supply. You would need to make sure that the amplifier could operate from that voltage, and would ideally be a rail to rail type, so can give an output from 0 to 5 V, not all opamps can.

I've shown the sensor connected directly to the mid-point resistors, with the mid point also going to the Ardunio's ADC for reference. It depends on the accuracy you're expecting, and the sensor and signal details whether this is sufficient. If the sensor output is large, it may be useful to buffer the midpoint voltage to the sensor with another amplifier configured as a unity gain follower. If the sensor cannot be referenced to a midpoint voltage but requires a ground connection to your circuit, for instance it's using a coaxial cable output, then a more complicated circuit would be needed.